# .htaccess убрать все между www и доменом

Tags: .htaccess, домен, mod-rewrite, поддомены

Как настроить редерект в `.htaccess` чтобы убрать все между `www` и `site.ru`. Чтобы не было под доменов в адресе `www.site.ru`. сейчас возможно вбить случайное название и оно будет грузить главную
`www.9087077.site.ru` - (такое не нужно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
# определяем, если доменное имя отлично от www.site.ru
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.ru$
# то делаем переадресацию на http://www.site.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.ru/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```